# How to remove Handler from adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, handler, android-adapter

I am using a function into an adapter and I added a Handler to do the refresh every 2s like below:

```
 final Handler refreshHandler = new Handler();
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         refreshHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
         myfunction();
     }
 };
 refreshHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

When I'm not into the fragment where I deploy the adapter the handler is always reloading.

So my question is, how to stop the handler every time I quit the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `removeCallbacks(Runnable r)` method.

That's how you put it in your code:

```
      final Handler refreshHandler = new Handler();
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         refreshHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
         myfunction();
     }
 };
 refreshHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);


@Override
public void onDestroy () {

    refreshHandler.removeCallback(runnable);
    super.onDestroy ();

}
```

Something like that wherever you want. Hope you understand

Comment: I don't know how to do that in an adapter

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look that should help you

Comment: that stop all reloads :)

Comment: use it when you want to stop the handler. i edited my code there is stopped when onDestroy Fragment ;)